# Codename one crash during capture audio

Tags: android, audio, record, codenameone

I'm getting a crash on our app on a part that used to work:
a call to Capture.captureAudio() to get the path to a newly recorded audio file.
I've tested on android and I get this stack trace:

```
[EDT] 0:5:30,336 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation.convertImageUriToFilePath(AndroidImplementation.java:5197)
at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation.onActivityResult(AndroidImplementation.java:4936)
at com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneActivity$9.run(CodenameOneActivity.java:506)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1150)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1094)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1204)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1242)
at com.codename1.capture.Capture.captureAudio(Capture.java:95)
at com.handover.app.taskhandlers.AudioTaskListener$AudioShowHandler.lambda$run$11(AudioTaskListener.java:86)
at com.handover.app.taskhandlers.AudioTaskListener$AudioShowHandler.access$lambda$0(AudioTaskListener.java)
at com.handover.app.taskhandlers.AudioTaskListener$AudioShowHandler$$Lambda$1.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(EventDispatcher.java:459)
at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:362)
at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:411)
at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:442)
at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:530)
at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:2613)
at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:2549)
at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:3147)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2024)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1066)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1204)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1242)
at com.codename1.ui.AnimationManager.addAnimationAndBlock(AnimationManager.java:105)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.animateHierarchy(Container.java:2465)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.animateHierarchyAndWait(Container.java:2185)
at com.handover.app.ui.components.ToastNotification.setVisible(ToastNotification.java:782)
at com.handover.app.ui.components.ToastNotification.updateStatus(ToastNotification.java:530)
at com.handover.app.ui.components.ToastNotification.removeStatus(ToastNotification.java:738)
at com.handover.app.ui.components.ToastNotification.access$700(ToastNotification.java:82)
at com.handover.app.ui.components.ToastNotification$Status.clear(ToastNotification.java:380)
at com.handover.app.ui.components.NetworkProgressIndicator.actionPerformed(NetworkProgressIndicator.java:55)
at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(EventDispatcher.java:459)
at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.access$100(EventDispatcher.java:45)
at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher$CallbackClass.run(EventDispatcher.java:95)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1150)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1094)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:995)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

It has been a while since this part of the app was throughly tested, and I'm not entirly sure which version of CN1 this was working on.
Capture.capturePhoto() and Capture.captureVideo() are both still working as expected.

Comment: just random guess, did you add permission for audio ?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />`

Comment: Since he calls Capture those should be included implicitly

Comment: There are no magicians on stack overflow u have to share you code

Comment: Please show your full code @peopletookallthegoodnames

Comment: We don't need code for that specific question as the stack clearly points to AndroidImplementation which is in the Codename One open source project here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/7c42e903fe5672d949c09dd234ceb6b0c1618e30/Ports/Android/src/com/codename1/impl/android/AndroidImplementation.java we are looking into this as it is quite odd...

Comment: is this used to work on that same device? or is this on a different Android?

Comment: Ok, I am seeing an issue with the current code, we will fix this for the next version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in current versions of the Android build